# OBIEE out-of-place upgrade from 10g to 11.1.1.9

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, business-intelligence, obiee

I'm planning to do an out-of-place upgrade for OBIEE from 10g on windows server 2003 to 11.1.1.9 on windows server 2012.

I find a document in the Oracle website below, which specify how to do an upgrade of OBIEE. However, may I know if it is applicable for an in-place update only? Could anyone please kindly recommend some useful references which specifies the steps required to perform an out-of-place upgrade as mentioned above?

[Upgrade Guide for Oracle Business Intelligence 11g Release 1 (11.1.1.9.0) E16452-09](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/core/FUGBI/toc.htm)

Comment: If there is not much of a response here, you might want to consider a service request with Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

This tells you all you need: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/core/FUGBI/bi_plan.htm#FUGBI436

There's no such thing as an "in place" upgrade from 10g to 11g. The Upgrade Assistant helps with the RPD and WebCat, but you still need to do the manual migration. It's well documented and several years later a well-trodden path so you'll find plenty of blog posts etc discussing any issues you may encounter.